# I added new RAM modules to my system, now I get unexpected shutdowns, why?

Tags: ram

Some days ago I increased my laptop's Memory to 16GB, Now  I'm facing unexpected shutdown, how I can check the reason my laptop is holding Ubuntu 13.10

```
Linux inspiron-3521 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Temperatures are the same as they where? Have you installed something new? Are you sure that the memory sticks you upgraded are OK (use memtest during boot), please give some more feedback on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you revert to your original memory configuration and run with that for a week. If the problem does not return, then change to the 16GB configuration. If the problem then returns, your memory is defective.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a program like MemTest86+ to test your memory. I always run the test overnight whenever i do an installation/upgrade of memory. This will let you know if you got some bad RAM.

Here is a link to the MemTest+ website: http://www.memtest.org/

If you get any errors at all then you know you have something wrong with your RAM. You can then pull the new sticks you installed for the upgrade and run the test again to make sure that you are not getting the errors from the old memory.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to test memory is to hold [shift] on startup. Then in the menu, choose "Test memory"

The test is quite long.